# FreeMarker can't access properties of a javabean

Tags: templates, javabeans, freemarker

According to the documentation, you should be able to pass a javabean to a FreeMarker template, and it will be able to access the getters of the bean. I've been trying to do this, but have not had any luck. Here's my code where I pass the bean to the template.

```
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Hello.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/templates")));
            cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
            cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.HTML_DEBUG_HANDLER);
            cfg.setIncompatibleImprovements(new Version(2, 3, 20));  // FreeMarker 2.3.20

            final String name = req.getParameter("name");
            // This works when model is a Map, but not when it is a bean
            Model model = new Model();
            model.setUsername(name);
            Template template = cfg.getTemplate("hello.ftl");
            template.process(model, resp.getWriter());
        } catch (TemplateException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unexpected template exception", ex);
            resp.sendError(500);
        }
    }

    private static class Model {
        private String username;

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to access `${username}` in a template, I get the following error.

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> username  [in template "hello.ftl" at line 8, column 10]

Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing... (snip)

The failing instruction (FTL stack trace):
----------
==> ${username}  [in template "hello.ftl" at line 8, column 8]
----------
```

I can get the template to work correctly when I use a Map. I've tried explicitly wrapping the Model object with various TemplateModel wrappers, but nothing I try seems to work.

Any hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Model` must be a public class for this to work.

Some other notes unrelated to the question: Use `setServletContextForTemplateLoading` instead `setDirectoryForTemplateLoading`, or else your app won't work if it's run from an unpacked `.war`. Also, of course you must not re-create the `Configuration` for each request, but I assume that's like that only for the sake of this example.

Comment: This fixed it. I checked the FreeMarker source, and they explicitly check if the bean is public. Only then do they try to discover the public methods. Not sure why they did that, since you can get the public methods of any object with reflection. Thanks for the other tips. Knew to not reinstantiate the Configuration object, but wasn't aware of the template loading.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why is that restriction there either... I have added this to my long long TODO list (me being an FM maintainer).